# Haskell implementation of Needleman-Wunsch

Tags: array, haskell, dynamic-programming

The code below is a Haskell implementation of Needleman-Wunsch algorithm for sequence alignment (and string edit distance). It's an experiment in trying to closely imitate the dynamic programming method as it would be implemented in imperative languages. Hence my use of mutable arrays and ST monad.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase          #-}

import Data.Array.ST
import Data.List
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad

-- Primitive edit operations 
data Operation a  = Subst a a  -- match is a special case of substitution
                  | Insert a
                  | Delete a
                  deriving (Show, Eq)

-- Operation costs
data Costs a = Costs {
    delete :: a -> Int,
    insert :: a -> Int,
    subst  :: a -> a -> Int
} 

defaultCost :: (Eq a) => Costs a
defaultCost =  Costs {
    delete = const 1, insert = const 1,
    subst  = \x y -> if x == y 
                     then 0 
                     else 10
}

data Transform a = Transform [Operation a] Int

-- Given cost functions, describe a series of transformation taking the input string to the output string
alignWithCost :: Costs a
              -> [a] -- ^ input string 
              -> [a] -- ^ output string
              -> Transform a 
alignWithCost Costs{..} inputString outputString = let
    inputLen  = length inputString
    outputLen = length outputString

    alignWithCostST = do
        array  <-  newArray ((0, 0), (inputLen, outputLen)) $ Transform []  0 :: ST s (STArray s (Int, Int) (Transform a))
        
        -- To get from x1 ... xn to the empty string, perform n deletions 
        -- the sequence of transforms is placed in reverse order ; later transform can then be appended with (:) 
        let initials = map reverse $ inits inputString
        forM_ (zip [0 .. inputLen] initials) $ \(i, initial) -> do
            writeArray array (i, 0) $ Transform 
                                       (map Delete initial) 
                                       (sum $ map delete initial)

        -- To get from the empty string to x1 ... xn to the empty string, perform n insertions 
        let initials = map reverse $ inits outputString
        forM_ (zip [0 .. outputLen] initials) $ \(i, initial) -> do
            writeArray array (0, i) $ Transform 
                                          (map Insert initial) 
                                          (sum $ map insert initial)

        -- To get from x1 ... xn to y1 ... ym, you either
        --   * go from x1 ... xn     to y1 ... y(m-1) and insert ym         (top)
        --   * delete xn and go from x1 ... x(n-1) to y1 ... ym             (left)
        --   * substitute xn for ym go from x1 ... x(n-1) to y1 ... y(m-1)  (diag)
        -- Pick whichever way is least costly
        forM_ (zip [1 .. inputLen] inputString) $ \(i, cIn) -> do
            forM_ (zip [1 .. outputLen] outputString) $ \(j, cOut) -> do
                Transform alignmentSeqLeft  initCostLeft   <- readArray array (i - 1, j)
                Transform alignmentSeqTop   initCostTop    <- readArray array (i, j - 1)
                Transform alignmentSeqDiag  initCostDiag   <- readArray array (i - 1, j - 1)
                
                let costLeft = initCostLeft + delete cIn
                    costTop  = initCostTop  + insert cOut
                    costDiag = initCostDiag + subst  cIn cOut
                    minCost  = min costLeft $ min costTop costDiag

                let toWrite
                       | minCost == costLeft = (Delete cIn):alignmentSeqLeft
                       | minCost == costTop  = (Insert cOut):alignmentSeqTop
                       | minCost == costDiag = (Subst cIn cOut):alignmentSeqDiag

                writeArray array (i, j)  $ Transform toWrite  minCost 

        Transform operations cost <- readArray array (inputLen, outputLen)

        -- Reverse the sequence of transforms to original order: earlier transforms before 
        return $ Transform (reverse operations) cost

    in runST alignWithCostST

 
align :: Costs a
      -> [a] -- ^ input string 
      -> [a] -- ^ output string
      -> [Operation a]
align costs inputString outputString = operations
                                       where Transform operations _ = alignWithCost costs inputString outputString

alignDefault :: (Eq a)
              => [a] -- ^ input string 
              -> [a] -- ^ output string
              -> [Operation a]
alignDefault = align defaultCost



printAlignSeq :: (a -> Char)
              -> [Operation a]
              -> IO ()
printAlignSeq display tokens = do
    forM_ tokens $ \case
          Insert _   -> putStr $ "_"
          Delete x   -> putStr $ [display x]
          Subst  x _ -> putStr $ [display x]
    putStrLn ""

    forM_ tokens $ \case
          Insert x   -> putStr $ [display x]
          Delete _   -> putStr $ "_"
          Subst  x _ -> putStr $ [display x]
    putStrLn ""
```

Here are some test runs:

```hs
*Main> printAlignSeq id $ alignDefault "a beautiful bike" "a big bike"
a beauti_ful bike
a b____ig___ bike
*Main> printAlignSeq id $ alignDefault "accgcag" "ccgacag"
accg_cag
_ccgacag
*Main> printAlignSeq id $ alignDefault "sinusoidal" "cosine"
__sin_usoidal
cosine_______
```

Any comments or feedback is welcome! I am particularly interested in the following points:

- Is this a good way to implement dynamic programming algorithms in Haskell?
- Is this a good way to mimic mutability in a language like Haskell?
- I am worried about memory issues: is there any unnecessary thunk build-up? how can I tell? (I really struggle to understand that!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about using mutability here. Sometimes it pays to just be straightforward and stick closely to something that you know works.

- You're not using `ScopedTypeVariables`.
- As far as the interface, `Costs` has no reason to be a `data` type. It is clearer from the user's perspective to say simply

  ```
  type Costs a = Operation a -> Int
  -- replacements for record accessors
  -- delete costs x   = costs (Delete x)
  -- insert costs x   = costs (Insert x)
  -- subst  costs x y = costs (Subst x y)
  -- e.g.
  defaultCost :: Eq a => Costs a
  defaultCost (Subst x y) | x == y    = 0
                          | otherwise = 10
  defaultCost (Insert _) = 1
  defaultCost (Delete _) = 1
  ```

  No more `RecordWildCards`.
- `Transform` currently also has no reason to exist: the only point it might have is documentation, but you haven't given it any! The `Int` is particularly mysterious at first sight. You should make it into a record with named fields (which will probably be self documenting enough). While you're at it, the total cost should be strict (I believe your code has a minor space leak in this field). "Accumulator" fields often should be strict.

  ```
  data Transform a = Transform { transformOps :: [Operation a], transformCost :: !Int }
  ```
- Taking a look at the main function

  ```
  alignWithCost costs input output = runST $ do -- no need to do strange things with lets
      let inputLen  = length input
          outputLen = length output
      -- (array? really?)
      -- (if you're going to comment about how the algorithm works, you should explain what this is)
      -- each partials[i, j] will eventually be the minimal transform from (take i input) to (take j output)
      -- also, the transformOps of the partials are reversed for efficient appending with (:)
      partials <- newArray ((0, 0), (inputLen, outputLen)) $ Transform [] 0 :: ST s (STArray s (Int, Int) (Transform a))

      let -- (a little vocabulary goes a long way)
          addOp op (Transform ops totalCost) = Transform (op : ops) (costs op + totalCost)
      -- (zip truncates; I find zipping with the infinite list cleaner)
      -- (there is no need to reverse each of the inits separately when we can write this iteratively)
      -- (your wasted space was here: I believe each Transform made in these loops would hang onto the corresponding list from the inits until you would start evaluating things down in the nested loop)
      -- (in this version, without the strictness annotation from before, this would still build some annoying thunks in the cost field)
      -- (compared to the total space usage though, I suspect it might be moot either way)
      -- for each partials[i, 0]: to get from x1 ... xi to the empty string, perform i deletions
      forM_ (zip [1..] input) $ \(i, del) ->
          -- (if we're mimicking imperative languages, may as well use all the application operators we have to sell it ;))
          writeArray partials (i, 0) =<< addOp (Delete del) <$> readArray partials (i - 1, 0)
      -- for each partials[0, i]: to get from the empty string to y1 .. yi, perform i insertions
      forM_ (zip [1..] output) $ \(i, ins) ->
          writeArray partials (0, i) =<< addOp (Insert ins) <$> readArray partials (0, i - 1)

      -- for all the rest of the partials[i > 0, j > 0]:
      -- to get from x1 ... xi to y1 ... yj, either:
      -- * transform x1 ... x(i-1) to y1 ... yj, then delete xi (using partials[i - 1, j] = "left")
      -- * transform x1 ... xi to y1 ... y(j-1), then insert yj (using partials[i, j - 1] = "up")
      -- * transform x1 ... x(i-1) to y1 ... y(j-1), then substitute xi with yj (using partials[i - 1, j - 1] = "diag")
      -- take the one with minimal cost
      forM (zip [1..] input) $ \(i, xi) ->
          forM (zip [1..] output) $ \(j, yj) -> do
              -- (so! very! clean!)
              left <- addOp (Delete xi   ) <$> readArray partials (i - 1, j    )
              up   <- addOp (Insert    yj) <$> readArray partials (i    , j - 1)
              diag <- addOp (Subst  xi yj) <$> readArray partials (i - 1, j - 1)
              writeArray partials (i, j) $ minimumBy (comparing transformCost) [left, up, diag]

      Transform ops cost <- readArray partials (inputLen, outputLen)
      return $ Transform (reverse ops) cost
  ```

  Having written all that, I do think that perhaps mutability actually is entirely unnecessary here. We can just use a single immutable array with an intricate recursion pattern:

  ```
  alignWithCost costs input output = Transform (reverse ops) cost
      where inputLen  = length input
            outputLen = length output
            xs = listArray (0, inputLen  - 1) input
            ys = listArray (0, outputLen - 1) output
            -- partials[i, j] is the minimum cost transform from (take i input) to (take j output)
            -- the transformOps are stored in reverse for efficient appending with (:)
            partials = array ((0, 0), (inputLen, outputLen)) [((i, j), partial i j) | i <- [0..inputLen], j <- [0..outputLen]]
            addOp op (Transform ops cost) = Transform (op : ops) (costs op + cost)
            -- this calculates each of the partials[i, j], potentially in terms of some of the partials[n < i, m < j]
            partial 0 0 = Transform [] 0 -- empty string to empty string
            partial i 0 = addOp (Delete $ xs ! (i - 1)) $ partials ! (i - 1, 0) -- (take i input) to []: delete each element
            partial 0 j = addOp (Insert $ ys ! (j - 1)) $ partials ! (0, j - 1) -- [] to (take j output): insert each element
            partial i j = minimumBy (comparing transformCost) [left, up, diag] -- (take (i - 1) input ++ [del]) to (take (j - 1) output ++ [ins]); choose of the following the minimal cost:
                where del = xs ! (i - 1)
                      ins = ys ! (j - 1)
                      left = addOp (Delete del    ) $ partials ! (i - 1, j    ) -- transform (take (i - 1) input) to (take j output) and delete del
                      up   = addOp (Insert     ins) $ partials ! (i    , j - 1) -- transform (take i input) to (take (j - 1) output) and insert ins
                      diag = addOp (Subst  del ins) $ partials ! (i - 1, j - 1) -- transform (take (i - 1) input) to (take (j - 1) output) and substitute del with ins
            Transform ops cost = partials ! (inputLen, outputLen)
  ```

  Yes, that's legal! (And it seems to work.) This is basically getting to heart of what memoization/dynamic programming is: `partial` is a recursive algorithm "at heart", but we've simply taken the recursive calls and redirected them to a lookup table (the transformation `partials ! (x, y)` <-> `partial x y`). In Haskell, we can trust laziness to populate that table as needed instead of writing it ourselves. We use an array over a list because lists are not meant for random access.
- For the helper functions, I can't say much, except that now `align` can just be

  ```
  align costs input output = transformOps $ alignWithCost costs input output
  ```
- `printAlignSeq` can probably be

  ```
  printAlignSeq display ops = do
      putStrLn $ flip map ops $ \case
          Insert   _ -> '_'
          Delete x   -> display x
          Subst  x _ -> display x
      putStrLn $ flip map ops $ \case
          Insert   y -> display y
          Delete _   -> '_'
          Subst  _ y -> display y
  ```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this excellent review! I can see the benefit of array+recursion+laziness to get some form of memoization going on. I'd be interested to know how this solution compares to the ST-based solution in terms of memory footprint.